# Oculus Quest 2 unable to view DLNA source on network

Tags: nas, powerline-networking, dlna, oculus-rift

My Quest 2 used to be able to view DLNA NAS sources on my local network. I think something on this new router I have is now preventing this.

Here’s the setup;

- Quest 2 is on 5Ghz WiFi.
- DLNA NAS is Ethernet wired into a TP Link power line extender via the mains circuit.
- Router is then also connected to another TP Link power line adapter then Ethernet from that to the router.

The above configuration used to work fine, but now I can only get my DLNA server to be visible to my Quest apps (e.g. Pigasus/DeoVR) so long as I put my DLNA NAS into a WiFi extender and connect to the router that way.

- i.e. It only works when both on a wireless network.

Same issue when plugging the DLNA NAS drive direct into the router without the power line adapters.

So essentially - unless both devices are on the WiFi, Quest 2 doesn’t see NAS on the network.

My TV and phone pick up the NAS DlNA when plugged into the Ethernet port or power line just fine, so it feels like some kind of Quest Update issue or maybe some network setting I’m missing?

Has anyone else had this scenario and have any advice? Or would have any advice on why a wireless device couldn't see a wired device on the same network? *Is it the same network?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some routers have a "wireless isolation" mode that needs to be disabled.

Comment: This could be it - I've raised a support ticket with Vodafone and I think this used to be a feature in previous firmware. Thanks for your help!